# Inverse kinematics for redundant robot

Tags: inverse-kinematics, matlab, robotics-toolbox, redundant-robots

I'm currently doing some in-depth analysis based on [this article](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/224567894_A_versatile_Generalized_Inverted_Kinematics_implementation_for_collaborative_working_humanoid_robots_The_Stack_Of_Tasks).
Starting from a general inverse kinematics solution, the article gives an appropriate formula to compute a solution that takes into account more than one priority-base tasks.

Now, I'm currently stuck on the very first step to follow the thread: *computing the inverse kinematics solution*. Simulating a **Kuka LWR4+**, I'm doing this in **MATLAB**, but it seems I'm neglecting something: the solution I get for just a single task does not follow the simple trajectory I've considered.
Since I'm also using the Robotics Toolbox, I've tried to use the IK solver that comes with it, and it does give me an acceptable solution, so I know there is (at least) one. But for studying and learning purposes I do have to come up with my code.

Below is a reduced (for simplicity) snippet of my code.

```
clc; clear all; close all;

syms t
syms q [7 1]

%% Numerical Data [cm]
l0 = 11; l1 = 20; l2 = 20; l3 = 20; l4 = 20; l5 = 19; offset = 7.8; rho = 10;

%% Denavit-Hartemberg and Jacobian
%                a   alpha   d       theta    joint_type
denavit = @(q)([[0,  pi/2,   0,      q(1),       "R"] 
                [0,  -pi/2,  0,      q(2),       "R"] 
                [0,  -pi/2,  l2+l3,  q(3),       "R"] 
                [0,  pi/2,   0,      q(4),       "R"] 
                [0,  pi/2,   l4+l5,  q(5),       "R"] 
                [0,  -pi/2,  0,      q(6),       "R"] 
                [0,  0,      offset, q(7),       "R"]]);

Jac = @(q, ind)(JacobFromDH(denavit(q), ind));

J = @(q)Jac(q,0); % J4 = @(q)Jac(q, 4);

Tos = HomX(0, [0,0,l0+l1]);
ForKine = @(q) Tos*DHFKine(denavit(q));

%% Task
t_task = 0:pi/10:3*pi;

% Desired EE motion
despos = @(t) [20 - 10*sqrt(3)*sin(t), 20*cos(t), 65 + 10*sin(t),0.5*t,0,sqrt(3)/2*t];
destwist = diff(despos,t);

traj_fig = figure2('Name', 'task trajectory');
grid
hold on
for k = t_task
    app = despos(k);
    plot3(app(1),app(2),app(3),'x--','Color','blue')
end
view(45,45)

%% Inverse kinematics algorithm
qSotNorm = sot(J(q), ...
               destwist',..., 
               ForKine(q), ...
               despos(t));

%% Plot solution
f_dot = figure2('Name', 'qSotNorm');
for j=[1:size(qSotNorm,1)]
    subplot(size(qSotNorm,1), 1, j)
    plot(squeeze(qSotNorm(j,end,:)))
end

%% Robot design
kuka = rigidBodyTree('Dataformat', 'column');

dhparams = [0  pi/2   0         qSotNorm(1,end,1); 
            0  -pi/2  0         qSotNorm(2,end,1);
            0  -pi/2  l2+l3     qSotNorm(3,end,1);
            0  pi/2   0         qSotNorm(4,end,1);
            0  pi/2   l4+l5     qSotNorm(5,end,1);
            0  -pi/2  0         qSotNorm(6,end,1);
            0  0      offset    qSotNorm(7,end,1)];

bodyNames = {'b1','b2','b3','b4','b5', 'b6','b7'};
parentNames = {'base','b1','b2','b3','b4', 'b5','b6'};
jointNames = {'j1','j2','j3','j4','j5', 'j6','j7'};
jointTypes = {'revolute','revolute','revolute','revolute','revolute', 'revolute','revolute'};

for k = 1:7
    % Create a rigidBody object with a unique name
    kukaBodies(k) = rigidBody(bodyNames{k});
    % Create a rigidBodyJoint object and give it a unique name
    kukaBodies(k).Joint = rigidBodyJoint(jointNames{k}, jointTypes{k});
    % Use setFixedTransform to specify the body-to-body transformation using DH parameters
    setFixedTransform(kukaBodies(k).Joint, dhparams(k,:), 'dh');
    % Attach the body joint to the robot
    addBody(kuka, kukaBodies(k), parentNames{k});
end

showdetails(kuka)

%% Integration
ris = cumtrapz(0.1, qSotNorm, 3);

fris = figure2('Name', 'with integration');
for j=1:size(ris,3)
    show(kuka, ris(:,end,j))
    view(45,45)
    drawnow
    pause(0.1)
end

hold on
for k = t_task
    app = despos(k);
    plot3(app(1),app(2),app(3),'o-')
end

eu_fig = figure2('Name', 'trying euler');
[ts, qs_eu] = ForwardEuler_sot(qSotNorm, 0, zeros(7,1), 0.1);
for j=[1:size(qs_eu,2)]
    show(kuka, qs_eu(:,j))
    view(45,45)
    drawnow
    pause(0.1)
end

hold on
for k = t_task
    app = despos(k);
    plot3(app(1),app(2),app(3),'o-')
end

%% Plot solution
f_norm = figure2('Name', 'integrated values with cumtrapz');
for j=[1:size(ris,1)]
    subplot(size(ris,1), 1, j)
    plot(squeeze(ris(j,end,:)))
end
```

```
function qsol = sot(J, xdot, FK, pos_t, kind, lambda)

    syms t
    total_time = 2*pi;
    step = 0.1;
    n_steps = ceil(total_time/step);
    n_joints = size(J, 2);
    n_tasks = size(xdot,2);
    syms q [n_joints 1]

    % +1 because the 1-index column of all pages will be qdot0(t)=0
    qdot = zeros(n_joints, n_tasks+1, n_steps);
    % Resulting in a (n_joints*1 x n_joints*1 x 1*n_tasks) matrix
    PA = repmat( eye(n_joints), 1, 1, n_tasks+1); % checked: OK to be an Identity
    % Extends twist vector to use the same index as the other matrices
    twists = cat(2,zeros(size(xdot,1),1), xdot);

    js = cat(3, zeros(size(J,1),size(J,2)),J);

    for i=[1:n_tasks] % i=2 <-> task 1
        current_task = i+1;
        prev_task = i;
        
        proj_prev = double(PA(:, :, prev_task)); % Projector of J_i-1

        for curr_time_step = [1:n_steps]
            timestep = curr_time_step * step;
            if curr_time_step <= 1
                prev_step = curr_time_step;
            else
                prev_step = curr_time_step-1;
            end

            % Jacobian: current task, previous timestep approximation
            jac = double(subs(js(:,:,current_task), q, qdot(:, current_task, prev_step)));

            % Desired twist: current task, current timestep
            twist_des = double(subs(twists(:, current_task), t, timestep));

            % Previous task final solution
            q_prev = qdot(:, prev_task, end);

            num_FK = double(subs(FK, q, qdot(:, current_task, prev_step)));

            posdes = double(subs(pos_t, t, timestep));
            err_pos = posdes(1:3)' - num_FK(1:3, 4);

            quat_att = MatToQuat(num_FK(1:3,1:3));
            quat_des = MatToQuat(eye(3)); % move out of this function
            n_des = quat_des(1);
            eps_des = quat_des(2:4);
            n_att = quat_att(1);
            eps_att = quat_des(2:4);
            % Can be computed via quaternions directly, too
            err_or = (n_att*eps_des' - n_des*eps_att' - Skew(eps_des)*eps_att');

            errors = [err_pos; err_or];

            k_pos = 50*eye(3);
            k_or = 50*eye(3);
            gains = [[k_pos, zeros(3,3)];
                     [zeros(3,3), k_or]];

            q_clik = pinv(jac) * (twist_des + gains * errors);
            q_app = q_clik; % so this is the starting point
    
            % Compute next timestep solution, for each task i
            q_next = q_app;% + pinv(jac * proj_prev) * (twist_des - jac * q_prev);

            % i-th task
            qdot(:, current_task, curr_time_step) = q_next;
        end

        proj_next = proj_prev - pinv(jac * proj_prev) * jac * proj_prev;
        PA(:, :, current_task) = proj_next;
    end


    qsol = qdot(:,2:end,:);
end
```

As you can see I'm using some code to perform DH-base Forward Kinematics and Jacobian computations; I've checked and those are good.

Does someone have any suggestions, even not code-related? I'm kinda confused, like I'm missing some core stuff...

**Thanks!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to help out someone in the future, here's what I've done.

The problem as treated above is ill-approached. I was trying to numerically compute the derivative terms hoping that I could integrate them later.

Turns out, the right way to approach this problem is to build your own function that computes a derivative function and then use the ODE family to integrate.
So, back to this case, for the inverse kinematics I've coded like the following

```
    function qdot = clik(tt, q, J_sym, twist_sym)
        % initialization
        n = size(J_sym,2);
        qdot = zeros(n,1);
    
        jac = J_sym(q);                 % 6xn
        proj_jac = pinv(jac);              % nx6
        twist_des = twist_sym(tt)';     % 6x1
    
        % actual function: qdot = J^(-1) * xdot_des
        for i=[1:n]
            qdot(i,1) = proj_jac(i,:) * twist_des;
        end
    end
```

and then used

```
[t_clik, y_clik] = ode15s(@(t,y) clik(t,y,J,destwist), [t0 tf], qinit);
```

where `destwist` and `J` are the function handles to compute the desired twist at the end effector and the manipulator jacobian, while `qinit` is the initial condition.

Answer (score 0):

I think this paper will help you.
[Analytical Inverse Kinematics and Self-motion Application for 7-DOF Redundant Manipulator.](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/ielx7/6287639/6514899/08630999.pdf)

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* eason. Thanks for your answer but we prefer answers to be self contained where possible. Links [tend to rot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_rot) so answers which rely on a link can be rendered useless if the linked content disappears. If you add more context from the link, it is more likely that people will find your answer useful. See [answer] for more info.

Comment: I'll look into that, thanks!